# Does this property of subgroups (or sheaves of ideals) already have a name?

Tags: gr.group-theory, ag.algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

I'm constructing an example of a group which has a particular property on its subgroups, and the property looks like something that might have been considered before.

Fix a group $G$ and a pair of subgroups $L$ and $H$. We consider a (non-symmetric) relation $s$ between $L$ and $H$:

> $L\ s\ H$ if and only if for all subgroups $K$, $H\cap K \le L \cap K$ implies $K \le L$.

The example I have in mind is this: Fix a set $M$ and a subset $N\subset M$. Consider also a group $\mathcal{G}$ and subgroups $\mathcal{H}, \mathcal{L} \lt \mathcal{G}$. Let $G = \mathcal{G}^M$, the set of functions from $M$ to $\mathcal{G}$ with pointwise multiplication. The subgroups are 
$$
H = \lbrace f\in\mathcal{G}^M |\forall n \in N, f(n) \in \mathcal{H} \rbrace
$$
$$
L = \lbrace g\in\mathcal{G}^M |\forall m \in M-N, g(m) \in \mathcal{L} \rbrace
$$
and it isn't too hard to see that $L\ s\ H$ in this case. I can't think of any other sorts of groups which have subgroups satisfying this relation, but I'm not a group theorist.

(PS if more tags are needed, feel free to add them)

---

**Addendum**

Having thought about this a bit more, it seems like I could be addressing this from a sheaf of rings point of view (a case of interest to me is $G=\mathbb{Z}$, or one could take the abelian group underlying a ring). In this case, we consider sheaves of ideals instead of subgroups, and look at the supports of the quotient sheaves. If they are disjoint then they satisfy a relation similar to the one defined above. Put this way, it seems like something quite natural arising from algebraic geometry.

Comment: If $K < L$ then $K \subset L$, so that $L \cap K = K$, which makes me think perhaps you mis-stated the relation you have in mind?

Comment: No. That's what I meant. A priori we don't know that $K\lt L$.

Comment: As you have defined it, $L$ $s$ $H$ if and only if $L \le H$.  Consider the case $K=L$...

Comment: @Colin: If I am reading it correctly, the condition $L\ s\ H$ means "The only subgroups that $H$ intersects into $L$ were already in $L$."  Put another way: "There are no subgroups $K$ of $G$ that are not subgroups of $L$, but that become subgroups of $L$ if you intersect them with $H$."  So, if you already know that $K$ is a subgroup of $L$, then checking the condition doesn't tell anything about whether $L\ s\ H$ or not.

Comment: Consider the case $G=\mathbb{Z}^2$, $H=2\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ and $L=\mathbb{Z}\times2\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @Theo - that is the correct interpretation, by the way.

Comment: Ah, I think the source of confusion was that I read '$<$' as 'is a proper subgroup'.  I usually write $\le$ for 'is a subgroup'.

Comment: Sorry, my fault. I realised when writing this out again to check that $L \lt L$ looked strange.

Comment: Assuming your '$<$'s are both '$\le$', it is sufficient to check the condition for cyclic subgroups, i.e. $L$ $s$ $H$ if and only if for every $x$ in $G \setminus L$, then $\langle x \rangle \cap H$ is not contained in $L$.

Comment: So couldn't we write it as: $L\ s\ H$ if and only if ($x\in L \leftrightarrow \langle x \rangle \cap H \le L$)?

Comment: That just leaves the issue of whether this has been considered before .... :-)

Comment: I don't recognise the property, but it seems quite special.  In the case of periodic groups, given $L$, there is a least subgroup $H$ such that $L$ $s$ $H$: $H$ is generated by the elements $x$ of $p$-power order (over all primes $p$) such that $x \not\in L$ but $x^p \in L$.  Then in general, $L$ $s$ $K$ if and only if $K$ contains $H$.  For elements of infinite order it's more complicated, as for instance $p\mathbb{Z}$ $s$ $q\mathbb{Z}$ whenever $p$ and $q$ are coprime.